# What's the difference between ${varname} and $varname in a shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix

I have a simple question but I wonder what is the difference between `${varname}` and `$varname` ?

I use both but I don't see any difference which could tell me when to use one or the other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `{}` in variable names helps get rid of ambiguity while performing variable expansion.

Consider two variables `var` and `varname`.  Lets see you wanted to append the string `name` to the variable `var`.  You can't say `$varname` because that would result in the expansion of the variable `varname`.  However, saying `${var}name` would help you achieve the desired result.

```
$ var="This is var variable."
$ varname="This is varname variable."
$ echo $varname
This is varname variable.
$ echo ${var}name
This is var variable.name
```

Braces are also required when accessing any element of an array.

```
$ a=( foo bar baz )       # Declare an array
$ echo $a[0]              # Accessing first element -- INCORRECT
foo[0]
$ echo ${a[0]}            # Accessing first element -- CORRECT
foo
```

Quoting from `info bash`:

```
   Any  element  of  an  array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}.
   The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion.
```

Comment: true, but incomplete. See post from fedorqui

Comment: +1 The question seems to only ask why braces would be used if no other parameter expansion syntax required them.

Answer (score 12):

They are the same in a basic case, but using `${varname}` gives more control and ability to work with the variable. It also skips edge cases in which it can create confusion. And finally, it enables variable expansion as described in [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> The ‘$’ character introduces parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, or arithmetic expansion. The parameter name or symbol to
>   be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to
>   protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately
>   following it which could be interpreted as part of the name.
>
> When braces are used, the matching ending brace is the first ‘}’ not
>   escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an
>   embedded arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter
>   expansion.
>
> The basic form of parameter expansion is ${parameter}. The value of
>   parameter is substituted. The braces are required when parameter is a
>   positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter is
>   followed by a character that is not to be interpreted as part of its
>   name.

Let's see a basic example. Here, the use of `${}` allows us to do something that a simple `$` does not. Consider we want to write `$myvar` + `"blabla"`::

```
$ myvar=23
$ echo $myvar
23
$ echo $myvarblabla
                        <--- the variable $myvarblabla doesn't exist!
$ echo ${myvar}blabla
23blabla
```

Answer (score 3):

The distinction becomes important when something follows the variable:

```
text="House"
plural="${text}s"
```

Without the braces, the shell would see `texts` as variable name which wouldn't work.

The braces are also necessary when you use the extended syntax to specify defaults (`${name-default}`), display errors when undefined (`${name?error}`), or pattern substitution ([see this article for other patterns](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html); it's for BASH but most work for KSH as well)

```
> echo $name-default
-default
> echo ${name-default}
default
```

Related:

- [Parameter Substitution in Korn-/POSIX-Shell](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/korn_shell_parmsub1.htm)